# Customize the Initializers of LSTM in R

Tags: r, keras, lstm

The documentation for Keras in R has shown multiple methods to initialise weights of a neural network. However, the method of customising the initialisation is not clear.

For example, I have a `3*3` neural network (or LSTM), I want to initialise weights by using my own `3*3` matrix. How can I do that in R?

Comment: Can you please show us your current implementation?

Comment: Now I only know how to use the methods that Keras give. I am sorry I do not know  how to initial weights by using a matrix that I defined.

Comment: If you show us your implementation (as well as initialising the weights).. one of us can adapt your code and give you an answer.